# Saving More Complicated Application Data

Tags: java, properties, file-extension, saving-data

For simple program data that needed to be saved I just used properties files before but I was wondering how I can save more complicated application data such as: arraylists e.g..

How would I save such data into a file? And is there a way to save it in a file with my own extension ( so not .properties for example when using the properties method to save data ) and to make sure it cannot be edited by user manually ( which is simply possible with notepad for example for .properties files )?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: You realize your property files don't have to end in `.properties`, right?  Filenames and particularly extensions are typically irrelevant in Java.

Comment: Ahh I actually wasn't even sure about that, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this as stated is to use the [built-in Serialization mechanism](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).  Just serialize your ArrayList out to a file using an `ObjectOutputStream` wrapped around a `FileOutputStream`.   As long as each item in your list is serializable, this will work fine.

It's not impossible to modify, but it's fairly obfuscated over, say, a text file (it's binary for starters).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I will get there with these info, the link was very useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Serialize to XML, encode/encrypt the data prior to persisting, and then decode/decrypt the data when consuming from your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self contained database like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)